# QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa

Tags: qgis, mac, osx, qgis-2.10

Since the version QGIS 2.8, each time I start to open it it begin wth this error message. I have Mac OS X 10.7.5 MacBook Pro, late 2011. It works but what do it means, and what should I do, I install updated version of

```
**An error has occured while executing Python code:
**RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 4
Python version:
2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)]****
```

QGIS version:
[2.10.1-Pisa Pisa](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog210/index.html),

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has been compiled with a different Python version then the one you have installed on your machine. **If it work's, don't worry!**